# How to get data from DialogFragent to main fragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment where I can choose from the list some value. The problem is when I choose a value from the list I don't know how to pass that value to my main fragment.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to communicate from activity to fragment?

Comment: @Ramz, I need to communicate from DialogFragment to Fragment. I have a Fragment from which I call DialogFragment and then depending on what user selects n DialogFragment, I need to change the value in main Fragment.

Comment: can you post snippet  of your code for understanding the flow of the code

Answer (score 1):

Define a method in `main fragment` and call it from `DialogFramgment`.

While setting values in list,call it as :

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).setValue(value_set);
```

And in MainActivity :

```
public void setValue(String value) {
        // Get the value
        value_selected_in_list = value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to pass data directly from one fragment to another.  You need to pass the data back to the Activity using a callback method.  Then the Activity can lookup the other Fragment by id and call a method on it directly to send it the data.  There is a tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).